# Complex Analysis - Convergence Of Series.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Write

$$z=re^{i\theta}$$
$$0< r< 1$$

> in the summation formula viz
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$$
>   $$\left | z \right |<1$$
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }r^n e^{in\theta}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }r^n({\cos n\theta+i\sin n\theta})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$$
>   Now, show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }r^n\cos n\theta=\frac{r\cos \theta-r^2}{1-2r\cos \theta+r^2}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }r^n\sin n\theta=\frac{r\sin\theta}{1-2r\cos \theta+r^2}$$

> I know that

$$Re\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}}$$
$$Im\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }r^n\sin n\theta=Im\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}}$$
$$u(z)=\sum r^n\cos n\theta$$
$$v(z)=\sum r^n\sin in\theta$$

> But where to from here?

Comment: Please state clearly which is your question. What would you like to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just compute the real and imaginary parts of $\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}}$? Multiply numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator

$$\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}}=\frac{1-re^{-i\theta}}{(1-re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})}=\frac{1-re^{-i\theta}}{1-2r\cos(\theta)+r^2}.$$

Now you can easily calculate the real/imaginary parts. If you want $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n\cos(n\theta)$ and similar sums, just subtract 1 from the real/imaginary parts of the above. Can you finish it from here?